# How best to update / upgrade RStudio inside or underneath Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, rstudio

The version of R Studio that is bundled with the latest release of the Anaconda distribution is over a year old [RStudio in Anaconda Navigator](https://anaconda.org/r/rstudio), specifically version rstudio-1.1.456.  If I check the Rstudio website [current RStudio download](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download), it says the latest version is RStudio-1.2.5033.exe.

I want to use the current RStudio release.  Anaconda Navigator package manager doesn't give me an option to install any later versions.  Also, Anaconda put my R-dedicated virtual environment (which I named `Rdev') and installed R in a wierd place too:`C:\Users\rlysakow.conda\envs\Rdev\Lib\R\bin`.

My judgement is that R and RStudio are basically UNIX programs that have been ported to Windows, and have all kinds of "leftover" Unix-izms and quirks in the way they reference files, directories, and scripts. Plus, Anaconda makes a lot of choices without always asking the user about where to put things.

It looks like to get a good RStudio update, I must update RStudio from within RStudio, but this will likely break a lot of Anaconda R functionality.  RStudio doesn't use Anaconda Navigator's `conda` program to do the upgrade.  The Anaconda Navigator's conda package index will likely not reflect the changes that RStudio makes.

Before I make a likely irreversible and breaking change to Anaconda, can anyone recommend a better way to do this Rstudio update and have Anaconda's package index correctly reflect changes that RStudio will make with executables and packages that it updates and installs?

Please do not recommend something like "ditch Anaconda and just use RStudio for all your R work", because that doesn't allow easy integration with Jupyter Notebook and the conda package manager inside Anaconda.  I could install Jupyter Notebook separately, but then I have to manager that outside of Anaconda too.  The end users of my application want to use Jupyter Notebook for their R work.